# Как использовать $.serialize() в ajax на wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Есть вот такой код и он работает:

```js
form.submit(function () {
   var data = {
       action: 'mig', // Указываем action который будет обрабатывать
       // Записываем значения полей. В проекте их гораздо больше и это сильно загромождает код
       name: $(this).find('input[name="message_name"]').val(),
       tel: $(this).find('input[name="message_tel"]').val(),
    };
    // Использую для проверки alert
    $.post( mig.ajaxurl, data, function (r) {
          alert(r)
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_mig', 'mig_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mig', 'mig_mail');

function mig_mail (){
    
    $name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? "Имя: " . trim($_POST['name']) . "\n" : "";
    $tel = !empty($_POST['tel']) ? "Телефон: " . trim($_POST['tel']) . "\n" : "";

    $message = "$name$tel";
    
    echo $message; // Использую для проверки

    wp_die();
}
```

Однако в реальном проекте полей больше и я хочу использовать `.serialize()`, чтобы код выглядел как-то так:

```js
form.submit(function () {
   var data = {
       action: 'mig',
       data: $(this).serialize(), // Удобная красивая запись. При возможном изменении полей в будущем можно будет сюда не лезть
    };
    $.post( mig.ajaxurl, data, function (r) {
          alert(r)
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_mig', 'mig_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mig', 'mig_mail');

function mig_mail (){
    
    $name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? "Имя: " . trim($_POST['name']) . "\n" : ""; 
    $tel = !empty($_POST['tel']) ? "Телефон: " . trim($_POST['tel']) . "\n" : "";

    $message = "$name$tel"; // Пустая строка

    echo $_POST['data']; // Вернет строку, 
    // например "message_tel=%2B7(215)364-75-86&current_services=&submitted=1" 
    // Как правильно достать нужные значения?

    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `urldecode` и `parse_str`

```
function mig_mail (){
    $data = urldecode( $_POST['data'] );
    parse_str( $data, $arr );
    echo $arr['message_name'];
    echo $arr['message_tel'];
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: нет, не так. сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: Протестировал и исправил.

Comment: Класс! Вы прямо можете отслеживать над какими задачами работаю. Вчера Вы же мне и подсказали как правильно работать с ajax на wordpress. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Как Вас зовут? Все равно на вопросы по wordpress отвечаете только Вы :D, так хоть по имени буду обращаться

Comment: Да неважно. Тут все по никам)